# Absolute continuity in terms of integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Below is the question and my attempted solution. I'm curious if it's correct, and if not can it be fixed? Or is it completely wrong?

> Let $\left(X,\mathcal{M},\mu\right)$ be a measure space, and let $\{\mu_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in[0,1]}$ be a collection of measures on the measurable space $\left(X,\mathcal{M}\right)$. Define,
> $$\nu(E)=\int_0^1\mu_\alpha(E)dx, \quad E\in \mathcal{M}.$$
> Show that, if $\mu_{\alpha}\ll \mu$-a.e $x$ in $[0,1]$, then $\nu\ll \mu$.

This problem seems almost too *easy*, so I figured I may be doing something wrong. Below is my solution:

Let $E_0\subseteq X$ be such that $\mu(E_0)=0$. As $\mu_{\alpha}\ll \mu$, it follows by definition $\mu_{\alpha}(E_0)=0$. By direct calculation,

$$\nu(E_0)=\int_0^1\mu_\alpha(E_0)dx = \int_0^10dx = 0\cdot1=0.$$

Therefore, by definition $v\ll \mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Seems okay. Just note that $\mu_\alpha \ll \mu$ only *almost everywhere* w.r.t. $\alpha$. Thus $\mu_\alpha(E_0) = 0$ for *almost* every $\alpha$. But that's enough to conclude that $\nu(E_0) = 0$ anyway.

This question looks like a fancier version of the usual $f = 0\ \text{a.e.} \implies \int f = 0$, maybe that's the nontrivial part.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$\mu_\alpha \ll \mu$ only *almost everywhere* with respect to $\alpha$"?